# How to join elements of an ArrayList converting it to a string representation?

Tags: .net, vb.net, arrays, string, arraylist

I 've an ArrayList and to join all its elements with a separator in one string I m using...

```
Dim s As String = String.Join(",", TryCast(myArrayList.ToArray(GetType(String)), String()))
```

however, I would know if there is a smarter/shorter method to get the same result,
or same code that looks better...

Thank You in advance,

Max

Comment: Any reason why you're using ArrayList instead of a generic collection?

Answer (score 4):

In Framework 4 it is really simple:

```
var s = string.Join(",", myArrayList);
```

In 3.5 with LINQ's extension methods:

```
var s = string.Join(",", myArrayList.Cast<string>().ToArray());
```

These are shorter but not smarter.

I have no idea how they should be written with VB.NET.

Comment: `String.Join(String, Object[])` was introduced in .NET Framework 4.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but since I've had to work this out for myself today, I thought I'd post the VB.Net solution I came up with:

```
Private Function MakeCsvList() As String
  Dim list As New List(Of String)
  list.Add("101")
  list.Add("102")

  Return Strings.Join(list.ToArray, ",")
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

I would make it an extension method of `ArrayList` e.g.

```
public static string ToCsv(this ArrayList array)
{
    return String.Join(",", TryCast(array.ToArray(GetType(String)), String()))
}
```

**Usage**

```
string csv = myArrayList.ToCsv();
```